# Using .roundedRect vs. cornerRadius of the layer for rounded corners

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I was experimenting with creating a simple textfield in code and have been using `UITextField.layer.cornerRadius` to create a rounded corner, rather than using .roundedRect property of borderStyle, which I thought looked more restrictive.

So I just came back to wondering about it, and would like to know if there is any advantage to using `.roundedRect`?
It seems to display a default standard roundedness of the corners - can this be adjusted, or is it just there to be available off the shelf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically tune the border width and corner radius of the text field and any other view for the matter, by accessing its `layer` properties:

```
UITextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
UITextField.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
```

On top of that, `UITextField` has a `borderStyle` property which you might want to play with. It has four possible values: `None`, `Line`, `Bezel`, and `RoundedRect`.

more check  [roundedRect apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextborderstyle)

> Displays a rounded-style border for the text field.

*Advantage is if you are using `.roundedRect` it will give standard **rounded-style & border Width** whereas if you use .cornerRadius you can tune programatically the **border width and corner radius***.

Comment: My question is if there are any other advantages associated with using .roundedRect instead of going into the layer of the view.

Comment: *Advantage is if you are using `.roundedRect` it will give standard **rounded-style & border Width** whereas if you use .cornerRadius you can tune programatically the **border width and corner radius***.